# How to extract DataContextChanged event to interface?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I am trying to extract an interface to be implemented by several views inherited from FrameworkElement. Like this

```
 public interface ILoadable{
        object SetModelAndReturn();

        void LoadControls();

        event TypedEventHandler<FrameworkElement, DataContextChangedEventArgs> DataContextChanged;
    }
```

But it fails with 
'FrameworkElement.DataContextChanged' cannot implement 'ILoadable.DataContextChanged' because 'FrameworkElement.DataContextChanged' is a Windows Runtime event and 'ILoadable.DataContextChanged' is a regular .NET event.

Is there a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem with KeyDown/KeyUp events using Explicit event handlers.

For example, given an interface

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
}
```

and a class

```
public class MyElement : UIElement, IFoo
{
}
```

I would get the error message

> 'UIElement.KeyUp' cannot implement 'IFoo.KeyUp' because 'UIElement.KeyUp' is a Windows Runtime event and 'IFoo.KeyUp' is a regular .NET event.

To solve this compilation error, I implemented the event explicitly.

```
public class MyElement : UIElement, IFoo
{
    event KeyEventHandler IFoo.KeyUp
    {
        add { this.KeyUp += value; }
        remove { this.KeyUp -= value; }
    }
}
```